# AttributeError when I use libsvm on python

Tags: python, libsvm

I'm trying to overcome some errors being thrown by the following snippet:

```py
import os
from libsvm.svmutil import *
from scipy.io import loadmat

data = loadmat(os.path.join('Data','ex6data1.mat'))
X,y = data['X'],data['y'][:,0]
model = svm_train(y,X,'-s 0 -t 2 -c 0.2 -g 2.8')
print(model)
```

Which produces this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Pythonlean\machine\venv\lib\site-packages\scipy\__init__.py", line 214, in __getattr__
    return globals()[name]
KeyError: 'ctypeslib'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Pythonlean\machine\Exercise6\test2.py", line 7, in <module>
    model = svm_train(y,X,'-s 0 -t 2 -c 0.2 -g 2.8')
  File "E:\Pythonlean\machine\venv\lib\site-packages\libsvm\svmutil.py", line 92, in svm_train
    prob = svm_problem(y, x, isKernel=(param.kernel_type == PRECOMPUTED))
  File "E:\Pythonlean\machine\venv\lib\site-packages\libsvm\svm.py", line 218, in __init__
    scipy.ctypeslib.as_array(self.y, (self.l,))[:] = y
  File "E:\Pythonlean\machine\venv\lib\site-packages\scipy\__init__.py", line 216, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(
AttributeError: Module 'scipy' has no attribute 'ctypeslib'
```

All package versions:

- `libsvm-official(3.25.0)`
- `scipy(1.9.0)`
- `numpy(1.23.1)`

Answer (score 0):

The library code of `libsvm-official` for version `3.25.0` contains a reference using `scipy.ctypeslib`, which doesn't exist. You have to either patch their code or update the library.

To quote [this issue comment](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/16775#issuecomment-1205441351):

> ctypeslib is actually from numpy. It is best to import it directly from there.
>
> Mirroring all of the numpy symbols in the scipy namespace was an early design decision that we probably wouldn't make again. FWIW, I recommend only using scipy for the subpackages it explicitly provides and ignoring all of the stuff mirrored from numpy. Import numpy stuff from numpy directly.
>
> The numpy mirrors were deprecated in #10290 (and the actual removal of ctypeslib and other modules imports from numpy in #15230, though that looks mostly incidental). Only functions got the deprecation warning treatment because it's hard to implement a deprecation of accessing a module, unlike calling a function.

The [corresponding PR where these were deprecated](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/pull/10290) was released in SciPy 1.4.0. Current code has to use [`numpy.ctypeslib`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/routines.ctypeslib.html). It's a bit surprising that `libsvm-official` 3.25.0 was released in April 2021, but the deprecation PR was merged in October 2019. Oh well.

The good news is that [according to the `libsvm` changelog](https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/%7Ecjlin/libsvm/log) the newest version 3.3 has this fixed:

> 3.3:  2022/8/11
> One-class probabilistic outputs introduced
> Use numpy Use numpy stuff directly instead of mirrored ones in scipy

So updating the library to `libsvm-official==3.3` should hopefully fix this issue. The release is brand new (the date above is pretty much "today" when I'm posting this), but it's [not on PyPI yet](https://pypi.org/project/libsvm-official/#history). Hopefully they will upload the release to PyPI soon.